# Defining multiple run commands with sbt

Tags: scala, command, sbt

I am using sbt 0.13.5. I have several sub projects in my project, in particular a spray client and a spray route server.
I want to be able to define several "run" commands, like runClient and runServer.
for each sub project, I create a mainClass and set it up in the sbt file.
Now, I would like to be able to:
- launch several sbt in different terminal sessions.
- in one session, type runClient
- in the other session, type runServer.
Is there a proper way to do that in sbt?  I tried to define runServer as a new command:

```
def runServer = Command.command("runServer") { state =>
    println("run Server")
    run in Compile in server
    state
}

def runClient = Command.command("runClient") { state =>
    println("run Client")
    run in Compile in client
    state
}
```

where server is my server project.
I add runServer in the commands of the project :

```
lazy val root = Project(id = "myproject", base = file("."),
    settings = commands ++= Seq(runServer, runClient)
).aggregate(client, server)
```

In sbt, if I type runServer, the println works, but nothing is launched.
Do you know how to execute the "run" statement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have to resort to commands to achieve what are you looking for. Simple tasks should be enough.

There is a caveat though. The `run` task, is an input task, and you have to convert it to normal task before referencing it.

#### build.sbt

```
val client, server = project

val runServer = taskKey[Unit]("Runs server")

val runClient = taskKey[Unit]("Runs client")

runClient := (run in Compile in client).toTask("args to the main class").value

runServer := (run in Compile in server).toTask("args to the main class").value
```

Now you should be able to run your server using `runServer` and client using `runClient`.

Note also that you can run both commands using `server/run` and `client/run` without resorting to custom tasks or commands.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that but I get an sbt error:  `> runAMServer
[error] Not a valid command: runAMServer
[error] Not a valid project ID: runAMServer
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: runAMServer (similar: runner)
[error] runAMServer`

Comment: Can you paste the output of the `projects` command and show how you have defined the tasks?

Comment: those are my tasks `val runAMTest = taskKey[Unit]("Run the AM Sever as Test")
  val runAMServer = taskKey[Unit]("Run the AM Sever")
  runAMServer := (run in Compile in amEndPoint).toTask("").value
  runTEEClient := (run in Compile in teeEndPoint).toTask("").value
``

Comment: oh. I need to add the tasks in the settings of the root project, right?

Comment: @Joel yes, in the root project.

Comment: I have to admit, I don't know how to do that :( But as you said initially, I believe I am overcomplexifying the problem, since I can just select the project and type run.